# Extern variable undefined

Tags: c++, undefined, extern

I am facing a problem with extern variable declaration. I have a bunch of .cpp files containing definitions of structs:

```
const System SystemA = {"A", 1, 2 ...}; //In A.cpp
const System SystemB = {"B", 1, 2 ...}; //In B.cpp
...
```

These Cpp files are just to server as a simple way to add new structs, and to look for one specific struct definition easily. (since I may have 100 definitions, and each of them is multiple [50] lines of code).

When I try to use them in another compilation unit (.cpp):

```
extern const System SystemA;
extern const System SystemB;
...

void InitStructs(){
    SystemA.Init();
    SystemB.Init();
    ...
}
```

I just get `undefined reference to SystemA` `undefined reference to SystemB`, and so on.
I am doing this unified initialization, because I was doing the initialization as a static dynamic initialization in each system.cpp. But that is risky since the order of initialization is not ensured (static initialization order fiasco). Therefore I was getting segmentation faults depending on the cpp compilation order.

I moved towards this approach, but now it doesn even compile....
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, `const` objects at global scope are by default also `static`, i.e., they are not visible outside the source file. To fix that, add `extern` to each of the definitions.

Comment: I mark this as the answer because it actually does explain that C, and C++ are nott the same. C defaults to extern, while C++ defaults to static on const variables.

Answer (score 1):

`SystemA` and `SystemB` should be defined with `extern` keyword, too:

```
extern const System SystemA = {"A", 1, 2 ...}; //In A.cpp
extern const System SystemB = {"B", 1, 2 ...}; //In B.cpp
```

Or you could make a header e.g. `Globals.h`, declare them:

```
extern const System SystemA;
extern const System SystemB;
```

This way it's guaranteed they'll have same linkage across all compilation units that include the header. Later, you can define them without `extern` keyword, since the `extern` declaration is already visible:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "Globals.h"

const System SystemA = {"A", 1, 2 ...};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "Globals.h"

const System SystemB = {"B", 1, 2 ...};
```

Comment: Oh, million thanks. It does indeed fix it! I though all non-static variables where externable by default. I think I should read the spec again.